# Microsoft Office Activation

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I purchased a PC from eBay which was outfitted with Office 2016 and Windows 10.

Is there a test that can determine if it merely a trial and will expire or if it is indefinitely activated?  I am not receiving the nag (yet?).

Update

[image]

Comment: why is a PC your getting off eBay using a KMS licensed product?

Comment: And if that information is correct... that PC is reporting back to the KMS server of 1.2.7.0 for activation ... every 180 days. It is activated ... but every 180 days it will need to re-activate to the KMS server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Is there a test that can determine if it merely a trial?

Please use the following procedure:

> In order to check the activation status of your Office 365/2016
>   install, you need to execute two small commands in Command Prompt.
>   complete the given below directions to know the activation status of
>   Microsoft Office 2016/365 on Windows.
>
> 1. The first step is to check the type of your Office 2016 or Office 365 installation.
>
>    To do so, open Word, Excel or any other Office application, click
>      "File" menu, click "Account", and then click "About Word" to check if
>      your Office 2016 or Office 365 install is 32-bit or 64-bit.
>
>    [image]
> 2. Open Command Prompt by typing `CMD` in Start menu or taskbar search box and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 3. In the Command Prompt, type the following command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
>    If Office 32-bit is installed on 64-bit Windows:
>
>    ```
>    cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16
>    ```
>
>    If Office 32-bit is installed on 32-bit Windows:
>
>    ```
>    cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16
>    ```
>
>    If Office 64-bit is installed on 64-bit Windows:
>
>    ```
>    cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16
>    ```
>
>    In the above commands, please replace `C` with the drive letter of
>      the drive where Windows is installed.
>
>    Important: If you’re still using Office 2013 as part of Office 365
>      subscription, replace Office16 in above commands with Office15.
>      Likewise, if you’re using Office 2013, please use Office15 in place of
>      Office16 in above commands.
> 4. Finally, type the following command to view the status of your Office 365 activation.
>
>    ```
>    cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus
>    ```
>
>    If the copy is activated, you will see "LICENSED" next to "LICENCE STATUS".
>
>    [image]
>
> And if you want to check the expiry date of your subscription, please
>   refer to our [how to check Office 365 subscription expiry date](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-check-office-365-subscription-expiry-date/)
>   guide.

Source [How To Check Office 2016/365 Activation Status](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-check-office-2016365-activation-status/)

Comment: This doesn't work for device based 365 activation.

Answer (score 0):

If Office is not activated it will nag every time you launch any of the associated programs asking you to active the product

Answer (score -1):

Please run the following from command line.  It should pop up the information you are looking for

slmgr.vbs -dli